# Full-window WebGL canvases in Chrome are incredibly slow

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I discovered I had a problem when I checked one of my uploaded three.js projects. At first I thought maybe I had done something wrong. My project used r63, so I updated to r65, but that didn't solve the problem, even after clearing the cache and refreshing. I then checked a couple of the demos from the three.js site, and I found they are slow for me, too. As an example, http://carvisualizer.plus360degrees.com/threejs/ autorotates incredibly slowly in Chrome, but at normal speed in Firefox and IE 11. I also tried http://helloracer.com/webgl/ which is fine in Firefox but really choppy in Chrome. It's a disaster in IE11, by the way, but it's an older demo. My project uses OrbitControls, with autorotate enabled. The model is a 16MB JSON file (200,000 triangles), but it worked fine before and works fine in Firefox and IE11. I'm on a Windows 7 machine with a GTX Titan (work computer). Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that my project and the first demo above both give the error message "S3TC compressed textures not supported" in the Chrome console. Relevant?

Comment: Just tried one of the Babylon.js examples that had worked for me previously, just on the basis of seeing whether it was a general WebGL issue or specific to three.js. 4 fps.

Comment: I think I sort of know the source of the problem. I noticed earlier this week (yesterday?) that the scrollbars in Chrome had changed in appearance and, more importantly, functionality. On some sites, it's no longer possible to click on the scrollbar -- it's necessary to scroll with the middle mouse wheel. On a hunch, I did a quick search for a three.js example that doesn't use the full browser window. This one doesn't have the problem: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_canvases_grid

Comment: You should report chrome bugs at http://crbug.com

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your reply until just now. I've submitted a bug report there. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem on OS X.

Answer (score 13):

type chrome://flags in chrome address bar, and look for settings #ignore-gpu-blacklist

this happened to me, suddenly my gpu was added to blacklist and chrome reverted to software rendering..

Comment: Thanks!   This was my problem.  I wonder why they blacklisted a Radeon r9 290... Seems like a pretty popular video card.

Answer (score 5):

For me running google-chrome on linux I needed to enable `Use hardware acceleration when available` in chrome://settings

[image]